# Reading multiple excel sheet

Tags: java, jxl, jexcelapi

I am trying to read the sheets of a spread sheet uisng a foor loop. I wanted to know is this the right way of reading especially the use of Sheet Propety [highlighted in the code] :

```
Cell[][] newcell=new Cell[200][200];   
int newsheet = workbook1.getNumberOfSheets();
for (int q=1;q < newsheet;q++)    
{
    for(int p=0;p < sheet(q).getColumns();p++)
    {
         for(int p1=0;p1<sheet(q).getRows();p1++)
                       /*^^^^^^^^^*/
         {
               newcell[p][p1] = sheet(q).getCell(p, p1);
                              /*^^^^^^^^^*/
               if(newcell[p][p1].equals(saved[j]))
               {
                    System.out.print( newcell[p][0]);
                }
          }
     }   
}
```

Can I use the property of sheet() as sheet(q) because its throwing `NullPointerException`?

Comment: *where* do you get a NullPointerException?

Comment: @Andreas_D for(int p1=0;p1<sheet(q).getRows();p1++) in this statement its throwing the Exception.

Comment: @user756742 - there must be something wrong inside your custom `sheet(int i)` method. `sheet(q)` sometimes returns an object and sometimes `null` for the same value of `q` - that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Andreas So now wat should I need to tackle this.???

Comment: I used POI before but your code is different to mine. Check this site http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html if can be a help. If it say NullPointerException it could be that you are pointing to row that not exist out of the range. Also looking at your code, I will try first to get the row then cell and will not use column similar to Gagravarr sample.

Comment: @user756742 - show us your `sheet(int i)` method, *please*.

Answer (score 3):

The usual style for working with all the cells in POI is:

```
for(int sheetNum=0; sheetNum < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetNum++) {
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNum);
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe switch your code to something more like that?

Comment: @Gagravarr : I need to wat does Row here mean is it a class for which I need to import some packages ??? I am using Eclipse and hae imported Jxl.jar already,but this does not provied anything like this.

Comment: What library are you using? Your question is tagged with Apache POI, which is what this answer refers to, but now you're mentioning JXL?

Comment: @Gagravvr - I had tagged under Java, anyways.. I am getting this error code "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable " for the sheet in the foor loop [for (Row row : sheet)] how do i over come it ?

Comment: @user756742 - `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet` implements `Iterable` and so the error you see shouldn't occur. You're using **jxl**, right?

Comment: @Adnreas_D No I did import the POI jar [jar name poi-3.2-FINAL]. Is there any version of POI that I need to use ? coz m not able to able to get the ss.usermodel option so as to include.

Comment: You'll want to use POI 3.7 final, or possibly 3.8 beta 2 (I'd recommend it if you can). 3.2 is too old for those features.

Answer (score 0):

With *jxl* ([JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/index.html)), this should work:

```
for (Sheet sheet:workbook1.getSheets()) {  // getSheet() returns a Sheet[]
  int numCols = sheet.getColumns();        // getColumns() returns an int
  for(for int i = 0; i <= numCols; i++) {
     Cell[] column = sheet.getColumn(i);
     for(Cell cell:column) {               // column is a Cell[]
        if(cell.equals(saved[j])) {
           System.out.print(cell);
        }
     }
  }   
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error code "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable " for the sheet in the foor loop [for(Cell[] column:sheet.getColumns())] how do i over come it ? for Jxl also .. :(

Comment: @user756742 - I don't know what you're doing. JavaDoc for JExcelApi clearly tells me, that `jxl.Workbook#getSheets()` returns an array of `Sheet` instances, so the first for loop **will** work (assuming, `workbook1` is a `jxl.Workbook` type - hope your not mixing Apache POI and jExcelAPI/jxl...)

Comment: I am not mixing Apache POI and Jxl API... I am declaring the workbook as
 Workbook workbook1=Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("filenamepath")); and have imported the jxl.Wookbook. I hope 'm using the jxl.workbook type only.

Comment: @user756742 - sorry *my mistake* - looked at the wrong for loop and my code has a bug - I'll correct it, hold on.

Comment: The first for loop is working fine the prob is only in the Second for loop.