# How to read an excel multiple sheet to store the content of excel sheet into database

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

I am new to java,
Now i have created the code for reading an excel sheet and sending it to the database using apache poi.
I have read the 1st sheet successfully with 1st query and sent it to the database, but i am not knowing how to read the 2nd sheet with the 2nd query and the table.
Here the 2 sheets have 2 different query,how to mention that in prepared statment.
Or is there any other way to do it.
Please do help me out with this issue.
The code is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>Excel</title>
</head>
<body>
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="Excel.jsp" METHOD=POST>
<br><br><br>
<center><table border="2" >
<tr><center><td colspan="2"><p align="center"><B>UPLOAD THE FILE</B><center></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b>
</td>
 <td><INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-  officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"></td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan="2">
 <p align="right"><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send File" ></p></td></tr>
 </center>
 </FORM>
  </body>

 <jsp:useBean id="connection" class="DB.DB_Connection" scope="page">
 <jsp:setProperty name="connection" property="*"/>
 </jsp:useBean> 
  </html>

 <%!     
   Connection con;
   PreparedStatement ps=null;
   PreparedStatement ps2=null;
   public static ArrayList readExcelFile(String fileName) throws SQLException
   {
     /** --Define a ArrayList
      --Holds ArrayList Of Cells

      */

      ArrayList cellArrayLisstHolder = new ArrayList();

     try{
           /** Creating Input Stream**/
          FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);

          /** Create a POIFSFileSystem object**/
           POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

          /** Create a workbook using the File System**/
           HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

          /** Get the first sheet from workbook**/

            HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
            HSSFSheet mySheet2 = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(1);


         /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
            Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
            Iterator rowIter1 = mySheet2.rowIterator();
             while(rowIter.hasNext()){
             HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
             Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
              ArrayList cellStoreArrayList=new ArrayList();

             while(cellIter.hasNext()){
             HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();

              HSSFCell cell;

          short i= 1;

          do {
              cell = myRow.getCell(i);// Start from first column

              if (cell == null) {
                 break;
              }
              if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                 // Plain String Cell.
                 System.out.println("The Cell is a String with value : "
                       + cell.getStringCellValue());
              } else if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {

                 // Excel stores the Date as a Numeric Contents. POI provides
                 // a Date utility to check
                 // if a particular cell is formatted as a date.
                 if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {

                    Date date = HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate((double) cell
                          .getNumericCellValue());

                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
                    System.out.println("The cell is a Date : " + df.format(date));
                 } else {
                    // treat the cell as 'double' number
                    System.out.println("The cell is a number : "
                          + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                 }

              } else if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                 // Some of the cells will be rendered blank when cells in
                 // Excel are merged... one such cell
                 System.out
                 .println("A Blank Cell Encountered.... any merging happened???");
              } else {
                 System.out.println("The cell is nothing we're interested in ...");
              }
              i++; // increment cell counter!!!
           } while (cell != null);

          cellStoreArrayList.add(myCell);

                    }
      cellArrayLisstHolder.add(cellStoreArrayList);
  }
  while(rowIter1.hasNext()){
      HSSFRow myRow1 = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
      Iterator cellIter1 = myRow1.cellIterator();
      ArrayList cellStoreArrayList1=new ArrayList();
      while(cellIter1.hasNext()){
          HSSFCell myCell1 = (HSSFCell) cellIter1.next();
          HSSFCell cell1;
          short i= 1;
          do {
              cell1 = myRow1.getCell(i); // Start from first column
              if (cell1 == null) {
                 break;
              }
              if (cell1.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                 // Plain String Cell.
                 System.out.println("The Cell is a String with value : "
                       + cell1.getStringCellValue());
              } else if (cell1.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {

                 // Excel stores the Date as a Numeric Contents. POI provides
                 // a Date utility to check
                 // if a particular cell is formatted as a date.
                 if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell1)) {
                    Date date = HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate((double) cell1
                          .getNumericCellValue());
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
                    System.out.println("The cell is a Date : " + df.format(date));
                 } else {
                    // treat the cell as 'double' number
                    System.out.println("The cell is a number : "
                          + cell1.getNumericCellValue());
                 }

              } else if (cell1.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                 // Some of the cells will be rendered blank when cells in
                 // Excel are merged... one such cell
                 System.out
                 .println("A Blank Cell Encountered.... any merging happened???");
              } else {
                 System.out.println("The cell is nothing we're interested in ...");
              }
              i++; // increment cell counter!!!
           } while (cell1 != null);

          cellStoreArrayList1.add(myCell1);

                    }
      cellArrayLisstHolder.add(cellStoreArrayList1);
  }
}catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
return cellArrayLisstHolder;
}


%>
<%

 File f = new File("DeptHosp.xls");
   System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());

  File file = new File("."); 
 for(String fileNames : file.list()) System.out.println(fileNames);
String fileName="D://PROJECT//SOFTWARES//eclipse_Juno//eclipse//DeptHosp.xls";             
System.out.println(" path found");
ArrayList dataHolder=readExcelFile(fileName);
//Print the data read
//printCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);

con=connection.getConn();
 System.out.println("Inserting the details");
 String query="insert into   departmentmaster(Dept_id,Dept_Groupid,Dept_Kid,Dept_Groupkid,Dept_Group,Dept_Name,Dept_type,Dept_HospitalId,Dept_datecreated,Dept_datelastrefreshed)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  String query1="insert into hospitalmaster(hospital_group,hospital_name)values(?,?)";
   ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
  ps2=con.prepareStatement(query1);
   System.out.println("Database");
  int count=0;
     ArrayList cellStoreArrayList=null;
    Date datevalue=null;

  //For inserting into database
    for (int i=1;i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
    cellStoreArrayList=(ArrayList)dataHolder.get(i);


   ps.setString(1,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).getStringCellValue());
   ps.setString(2,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).getStringCellValue());
   ps.setString(3,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(2)).getStringCellValue());
   ps.setString(4,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(3)).getStringCellValue());
   ps.setString(5,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(4)).getStringCellValue());
   ps.setString(6,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(5)).getStringCellValue());
   ps.setString(7,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(6)).getStringCellValue());
   ps.setString(8,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(7)).getStringCellValue());
   ps.setString(9,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(8)).getStringCellValue());
   ps.setString(10,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(9)).getStringCellValue());
   count= ps.executeUpdate();
   ps2.setString(1,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).getStringCellValue());
   ps2.setString(2,((HSSFCell)cellStoreArrayList.get(1)).getStringCellValue());
   count= ps2.executeUpdate();

   }

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading multiple excel sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056427/reading-multiple-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are mixing things.  You have already solved how to present a JSP, read an Excel file with POI and write rows into a database.  I suggest you to redesign your code to separe those tasks.  Maybe a simple class (Reader.java) which only reads the excel file and produces an `ArrayList` for each sheet, and then a simple class (Writer.java) with 2 methods, each of which takes an `ArrayList` and writes them to the database as needed.  That leads to a more simple top-down design, which would be easier to debug.

By the way, you are creating a database connection in your code and not returning it.  You should call the `.close()` method for every database resource (`ResultSets`, `Statements` and `Connections`) that you use in your application, or use some idiom (try with resources, Spring resources management, whatever) that makes sure to do so.

Bonus track: when you feel more comfortable with java, have a look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

This would be the preferred manner to connect to a database in a web application with, potentially, hundreds or thousands of concurrent users.  Your idea, opening a new connection for each access to your page, which is perfectly right for an academic exercise, would lead to efficiency problems in a real environment.  Maybe your application server has a built-in connection pool mechanism (latest version of tomcat, weblogic, websphere have them for example) or maybe you could consider using apache DBCP or C3PO.